# PhpStorm - Folding automatically all method bodies, excluding active method

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Is there a way to automatically collapse all method bodies and display only the method body where the cursor is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set method bodies to be collapsed automatically at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding | PHP method body`.

However, you can't make PhpStorm collapse the method body when you move the cursor away to another method. There's also no action to at least bring folding to the default state: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80100